# How to chain where conditions with "or" in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app I need to find all `plans` that do either have an `interval` of `month` *OR* an `amount` of `0`.

This doesn't work:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.by_interval(interval)
    where("interval = ? OR amount = ?", interval, 0)
  end

end
```

I am getting this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'month' OR amount = 0)  ORDER BY amount DESC' at line 1: SELECT `plans`.* FROM `plans`  WHERE (interval = 'month' OR amount = 0)  ORDER BY amount DESC
```

What else might work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you have a type issue. Would have been helpfull if you posted the syntax error. I guess your interval is a string. so try: where("interval like '?' OR amount = ?", interval, 0)

Comment: Tried that but didn't work. The syntax errors I am getting all look similar: `Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE ''month'' OR amount = 0)' at line 1: SELECT plans.* FROM plans  WHERE (interval LIKE ''month'' OR amount = 0)`

Comment: sorry, remove the single quotes again and update your question with the original syntax error please.

Comment: Okay. Update posted above.

Comment: What datatype is `interval`? Is it a kind of string/text/varchar?

Comment: @RubyRacer: Yes, string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'interval' in mysql is a reserved word (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

Try it like this:

```
def self.by_interval(interval)
  where("`interval` = ? OR amount = ?", interval, 0)
end
```

note the backticks around "interval" (not quotes)

Comment: Wow, surprisingly that finally works! Thank you. I just wonder if I should better rename the column to something else if `interval` is a reserved word.

Comment: Looks like this is only a problem if you write your queries like this yourself. If you do things like "where(:interval => interval)" Rails already handles it in the generated sql. So I don't think renaming is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not doing an exclusive or, but an inclusive, I would do it in two requests:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.by_interval(interval)
    where(interval: interval) << where(amount: 0)
  end
end
```

These are both arrays of results and the second set of results get injected into the first.  I do realize this is two separate requests so it might not be as optimized as you'd like.

I believe using Rails ActiveRecord caching may be a way to save on a performance hit.  I don't know if it's done automatically for you in this case, or if you should load the full table request before the queries are performed.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass the arguments directly into the strings

```
def self.by_interval(interval)
  where("interval = #{interval} OR amount = 0")
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted, but if your interval variable is a string you just have to wrap it with single quotes

Comment: Thanks, but both suggestions didn't work. I keep getting MySQL syntax errors.

Comment: @boulder_ruby I didn't downvote, but perhaps one reason is that adding interpolated values in SQL could result in SQL Injection vulnerabilities.  I think your answer is correct, but would be improved by `where("interval = ? OR amount = 0", interval)` to avoid this issue.

Comment: I know this isn't a good answer, but maybe "Switch to PostgreSQL" (or SQLite3) is your best solution